# Regex for SoundCloud URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I just want to match my url with this URL
all possible combinations like www without www, http,https

Basically any input URL that matches with soundcloud music url like

https://soundcloud.com/mazz-ika-free/wegz-molotof-dorak-gai-2020

FIRST PART:- https://soundcloud.com/ (http,https) 
SECOND PART :- Alphanumeric with only '-' allowed. 
THIRD PART :-  Aphanumeric with only '-' allowed

I have tried this regex so far :

```
/^https?:\/\/(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)\/(.*)$/
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SoundCloud the following rules apply to links (everything after soundcloud.com):

- Use only numbers, lowercase letters, underscores, or hyphens.
- Profile URLs must not start or end with an underscore or hyphen.
- Profile URLs must not have two consecutive underscores or hyphens.
- Profile URLs must be between 3 and 25 characters.

I've written a regex pattern for the entire link:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)((?:www\.)|(?:m\.))?soundcloud\.com\/[a-z0-9](?!.*?(-|_){2})[\w-]{1,23}[a-z0-9](?:\/.+)?$
```

Here's a version without all the non-capturing groups:

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.|m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[a-z0-9](?!.*?(-|_){2})[\w-]{1,23}[a-z0-9](?:\/.+)?$
```

Test it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/OWbj5s/5

Answer (score 1):

You could match either soundcloud.com or snd.sc followed by a repeating pattern matching a `/` followed by 1+ word chars.

The word chars part by itself also has a repeating part matching a `-` and 1+ word chars.

If you only want to match alphanumeric, you could use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `\w` which could also match an `_`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)(?:\/\w+(?:-\w+)*)+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^https?:\/\/(?:soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)` Match the protocol and either soundcloud or snd
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/\w+` Match `/` and 1+ word chars
  - `(?:-\w+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single `/` part
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nvIAK4/1)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a new anchor `<a>` element from JavaScript, assign the URL to the `href` attribute, and then check the `host` property of that anchor:

```js
function checkURL(input) {
    var url = document.createElement('a');
    url.href = input;
    return url.host === "soundcloud.com" || url.host === "snd.sc";
}

console.log(checkURL("https://soundcloud.com/mazzikafree/wegz-molotof-dorak-gai-2020"));
console.log(checkURL("https://snd.sc/mazzikafree/wegz-molotof-dorak-gai-2020"));
console.log(checkURL("http://www.google.com"));
```

Here, you would be checking that the `host` is either `soundcloud.com` or `snd.sc`.

Comment: Hi Tim, Are we just checking the domain here ?. or we are checking the full URL.

Comment: Tim,want to check if that entered URL matches with the soundcloud url format, that i have given.

Comment: OK...I have updated my answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: Tim, Please have a look at the question. It says input URL should match with the format of sound cloud URL (that i have specified). You are just checking for the domain name.

Comment: Your answers passes this case : https://soundcloud.com/thechains928932%%5E%5E@#&@mokers/clean-bandit-jess-glynne-real-love which is not a valid one. Please refer to format first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have forgotten the `backslash` before the normal `slash` char.
Try this:

```
^https?:\/\/(soundcloud.com|snd.sc)\/(.*)$
```

Comment: Then it is probably due to something else. Here you can see it tested. https://regex101.com/r/Br52uW/1
Also make sure you remove the `slash` before the `^` character!

Comment: Hi,please check for this : https://soundcloud.com/mazzi--****9348*#$#*kafree/wegz-molotof-dorak-gai-2020 , which is not a valid case, your answer returns a match here

Comment: Please read format of URL (FIRST_PART, SECOND_PART,THIRD_PART in question)

Comment: ah, I see: try this
`^https?:\/\/(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)(\/?\w+\-?\w+?)*$`
You also forgot to put a `backslash` before your `.` chars.

Comment: Also, i want to know, if we could make it work in case of youtube URL too?.

Comment: sure, it's the same thing. Change the domain to `youtube.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var re = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)\/.*$/
```

I've tested following:

1. With and without www
2. http, https, no http specifier (simply soundcloud.com/mazzikafree/wegz-molotof-dorak-gai-2020)
3. soundcloud.com or snd.sc

If you require http specifier, then consider using

```js
var re = /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(soundcloud\.com|snd\.sc)\/.*$/
```

Comment: It say's syntax error. How should i use in javascipt?. Also, what if the middle part contains '-'.